# node.js API respond not terminated "can't sent headers after they are sent."

Tags: node.js, api, http-headers

The first request works fine, but after another request I got this Error Message. My logic does not double request, but it looks like, that each route isn't called seperately.

So the first request to `/api/user` works fine. After a refresh I got the error `Can't set headers after they are sent.`

`res.end()`  doesn't produce any error.

`res.send()` and `res.json()` and `res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json'); res.end();` will produce errors on a refresh.

In another API `res.json()` works fine, but there is no use of classes/functions nor EventEmitter. Maybe the problem is there?

routes.js

```
route.get("/", function(req, res) {
    user.on('error', function(err) {
        res.status(400).send({code: 900, message: err, data: null});
    });
    user.on('success', function(result) {
        res.status(200).send({code: 200, message: 'OK', data: result});
    });
    user.getAll();
});
```

user.js

```
var util = require('util');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var initialize = require(global.__base + "/config");
var db = initialize.db();

function User() {
    var self = this;
    this.get = get;


    function _checkForErrors(error, rows, reason) {
        if (error) {
            self.emit('error', error);
            return true;
        } else if (reason) {
            self.emit('failure', reason);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function _getData(error, rows) {
        if (_checkForErrors(error, rows)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            self.emit('success', rows);
            return true;
        }
    }

    function getAll() {
        db.query("SELECT * FROM patient", _getData);
    }
}
util.inherits(User, EventEmitter);
module.exports = User;
```

db init

```
module.exports = {
    globalModules: function() { /*foo*/ },

    db: function() {
        var mysql = require('mysql');
        var db = mysql.createPool({
                host:       'localhost',
                user:       'root',
                password:   '',
                database:   'node_docx'
            });
        return db;
    }
};
```

Comment: put your user route

Answer (score 0):

you need to `return` the *response*, to terminate the process:

```
route.get("/", function(req, res) {
    user.on('error', function(err) {
        return res.status(400).send({code: 900, message: err, data: null});
    });
    user.on('success', function(result) {
        return res.status(200).send({code: 200, message: 'OK', data: result});
    });
    user.getAll();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

finally I ended up to create a BaseModel which handles the response... every model (like User) will now inherit from this one.

```
var basemodel = BaseModel.prototype;

function BaseModel() {
    self = this;
};

basemodel.sendResponse = function(res, obj) {
    if (!res.getHeader('Content-Type')) { 
        res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }
    obj.on('error', function(err) {
        return res.status(400).end(JSON.stringify({code: 901, message: err, data: null}));
    });
    obj.on('failure', function(fail) {
        return res.status(400).end(JSON.stringify({code: 902, message: fail, data: null}));
    });
    obj.on('success', function(result) {
        return res.status(200).end(JSON.stringify({code: 200, message: 'OK', data: result}));
    });
};
```